# "Thus" or "so" to connect two sentences

Tags: transitions

> Nowadays, computers have become useful facilities at home. Whereas, they also bring a harmful impact to young students of those who use it frequently. **Thus|So** I believe their demerits overwhelmingly exceed their merits if too much time is spent on it.

In this writing, which one between *thus* and *so* is an appropriate linking word that should be used to connect the last two sentences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question:

> Use "**Thus,**" in a formal paper. You can also use "**Therefore,**".

If you're writing informally, it doesn't matter, but beginning a sentence with "So" is generally considered unacceptable in formal written English. Most peer reviewers and editors will ask that it be changed.

The three sentences you've written need editing. Here's one possibility (not the best, not optimal, but it corrects some grammatical errors and eliminates **some** of the verbosity):

> Computers have become useful and, in some cases, necessary facilities at home. Nevertheless, they also have a harmful effect on young students who frequently use them. Thus, I believe that their demerits overwhelmingly outweigh their merits for those who spend too much time on them.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit about the difference between "nevertheless" and "whereas"?

Comment: @canoe: In academic prose, _whereas_ is a synonym for _but_, which implies a contrast: _Rum is made from sugar cane, {**but** / **whereas** [CHOOSE ONE]} gin is made from juniper berries_. _Nevertheless_ also implies a contrast & can sometimes be a synonym for _but_: _Wild Turkey's 50% alcohol & Bailey's Irish Cream's only 17% alcohol{, **but** / ; **nevertheless** [CHOOSE ONE]}, a fifth of Wild Turkey makes me feel real good, & a bottle of Bailey's makes me puke my guts out_. You can say "Whereas a fifth of Wild Turkey makes me feel real good, a bottle of Bailey's makes me puke my guts out".

Comment: @canoe Also, *whereas* should be avoided at the beginning of a sentence, where it is ambiguous: it has the alternative meaning *Given that* or *In light of the fact that*. This use is common in Proclamations.

Comment: +1 In the humanities, at least, sentence-initial *So* is acceptable as a very strong marker that what follows summarizes a fairly long preceding argument. It is particularly favored at the beginning of a paragraph or section which will take that summary as the springboard for development (or contradiction) in a new direction. "So the critical consensus is that Grisilde is a model of wifely virtue; but do the events of the *Tale* justify this reading? I think not. ..."

Comment: @StoneyB: Really? Has the _MLA Style Manual_ accepted sentence-initial _So_? Good! I haven't used that manual for 35 years. I hope the style-tyrannosauruses soon die out. I prefer to use contractions, to start sentences with conjunctions, & to otherwise write more naturally than is usually allowed in academic rags.

Comment: @BillFranke I have no idea what MLA accepts or prohibits (I only consult it for documentation style), but Real Writers of all sorts use *so* (and other coordinating conjunctions) all the time to introduce sentences. What is to be eschewed (to my mind) in formal writing is the colloquial use of *So* as a mere 'discourse marker': "So what are you doing tonight?"

Comment: @StoneyB: Yes, they do, & so do I. Biomed journals have their own house styles or else use the AMA, CBE, or APA manuals.